# LocalNotification Event When App is Suspended in Background

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have an iOS app which uses local notification. The user can leave the app and check his/her email or do any other stuff. After a while 20 minutes local notification fires and alert the user with some message. At that time when local notification is triggered can I somehow handle any event. The didReceiveLocalNotification is only triggered when the user clicks on the notification.

NOTE: I do not want to fire the event when the user clicks on the notification. I want to fire the event when the local notification is triggered.

Thanks,

Comment: What event are you trying to handle...?

Comment: Any event that tells me that the local notification has fired!!

Answer (score 0):

When the user click then the app will open up via didFinishlaunching you can check whether it is launched because of local notification and do your stuff.

**Update:** You `don't have any delegate` to notify you that local notification has fired when the app is in background.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

     UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

}
```

Comment: This event is never fired when the application is not in the foreground and the user has not clicked on the local notification message.

Answer (score 0):

You can not track the event which will let you know that local notification is fired or about to fire.

Answer (score 0):

Local notifications are designed to be notifications for the user, not for your app.

You could provide more details of what you are trying to accomplish but you might be better off looking into [background app refresh](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4211?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) or [remote notifications with a content-available flag](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW58)